# How to change directory to unknown subdirectory

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file

I'm writing a short batch program to copy *.doc

The files are in directories where it's name can be changed.
In each directory, only have one folder only.

If in DOS command window, i'll just key-in `cd <press-TAB>`, then it will show the first available directory (or in my case, the only folder that have in that current directory)

Example:

```
C:\Book2014> cd "press-TAB"
C:\Book2014> cd English     // the only available directory to go
```

Is there a way of doing this in batch file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for /d %%F in (*) do cd "%%F" & goto :break
:break
```

The GOTO is there just in case there are more than 2 folders - it will CD to the first one found.

Comment: it works man :).. appreciate your help!